# Xamarin Forms + VS2017 + NETStandard: XAML and code behind are not grouped

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I added two pages by "Add\New Item" and choosing "Content Page".

The XAML and code behind are not grouped, the .cs should depend on the XAML.

Is this a known issue in VS 2017?
I spent a lot of time updating tooling only to discover this isn't working.... I hope it's a problem on my local installation.

Can someone please confirm?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the new way the **.csproj** file works when you change over to .NET Standard. Instead of including each and every file and describing how each file should be nested, the new way to do things is to only explicitly include files you want to ignore and use wildcards for things like nesting all files of a similar type.

So to fix the issue you can use the following method that I found from [this](https://oren.codes/2017/04/23/using-xamarin-forms-with-net-standard-vs-2017-edition/) site, just add the following to your .NET Standard project's **.csproj** file and remove any explicit include lines that are left over or that you added after moving things over to .NET Standard:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=55591 -->
  <None Remove="**\*.xaml" />

  <Compile Update="**\*.xaml.cs" DependentUpon="%(Filename)" />
  <EmbeddedResource Include="**\*.xaml" SubType="Designer" Generator="MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

So what the above is saying is:

- Remove all **.xaml** files
- Add all **.xaml.cs** files to the project, set their `Build Action` to `Compile`, and make them dependent on the filename of the file being added (without the extension)
- Finally add all of the **.xaml** files to the project, set their `Build Action` to `EmbeddedResource` and set their `Custom Tool` property to `MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml`.

This replicates how the old **.csproj** file would describe each and every file but just uses wildcards to that each file does not need to be listed.

If you also use ReSharper, a bug is preventing intellisense from working, a bug report can be found [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FRSRP-465198). One solution to this that was mentioned was to give XAML intellisense handling to Visual Studio instead of ReShaper (though this did not fully fix the issue for me):

[image: Showing ReSharper Intellisense Settings Window]

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I didn't migrate to NETStandard, I created a project from scratch. Let me edit the .csproj, and see how it works.

Comment: @MagnusMio This post was made when .Net Standard support was even worse than it is now. Any bugs you find now are probably related to something different.